# framer-motion get() method doesnt work with % width

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

I want to add scroll progress using `framer-motion`. I want to do this using `width` property and I tried the following:

```
export const ScrollProgress = ({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) => {
  const { scrollYProgress } = useScroll();

  return (
    <div>
      <motion.div
        style={{
          transformOrigin: 'left',
          backgroundColor: 'blue',
          position: 'sticky',
          top: '80px',
          width: `${scrollYProgress.get() * 100}%`,
          height: '20px',
          zIndex: 10,
        }}
      />
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};
```

It doesnt work :( Then I tried the following:

```
export const ScrollProgress = ({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) => {
  const { scrollYProgress } = useScroll();
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState<number>(scrollYProgress.get());

  useMotionValueEvent(scrollYProgress, 'change', (latest) => {
    setProgress(latest);
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <motion.div
        style={{
          //   scaleX: scrollYProgress,
          transformOrigin: 'left',
          backgroundColor: 'blue',
          position: 'sticky',
          top: '80px',
          width: `${progress * 100}%`,
          height: '20px',
          zIndex: 10,
        }}
      />
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};
```

and it works. How can I made it without introducing additional state like `progress`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`useTranform`](https://www.framer.com/motion/use-transform/) hook to map the scroll progress to a percentage like so:

```
// scrollYProgess returns a value between 0 and 1. We want the width
// to be 0% when scrollYProgress is 0 and 100% when scrollYProgress is 1.

const width = useTransform(scrollYProgress, [0, 1], ["0%", "100%"]);
```

The `useTransform` hook can be used [to map one motion value into a new motion value](https://www.framer.com/motion/use-transform/##mapping). Since `scrollYProgress` is a motion value, you can map it to the width percentage you want. The reason `width: '${scrollYProgress.get() * 100}%'` wasn't working is because using `.get()` on a motion value runs outside of reacts render.

[Here is a working example](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/scrollprogressy-width-example-85342k?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx%3A14%2C23&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpr31se70006356h7753i42s%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpr31se60002356hz9ge0w3m%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpr31se60004356hnw8rv7do%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpr31se70005356hnbkio10h%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B60%252C40%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clpr31se60002356hz9ge0w3m%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpr31se60002356hz9ge0w3m%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpr64den0002356hohrnhbnn%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A14%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A23%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A14%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A23%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252FApp.tsx%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clpr64den0002356hohrnhbnn%2522%257D%252C%2522clpr31se70005356hnbkio10h%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpr31se70005356hnbkio10h%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A5173%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpr3drcs00wv356hwob5fqfv%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clpr3drcs00wv356hwob5fqfv%2522%257D%252C%2522clpr31se60004356hnw8rv7do%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpr31se60004356hnw8rv7do%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clpr3dmg700u9356hgiewkb62%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpr3dmg700u9356hgiewkb62%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%255D%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)